# Mininum order amount for existing customers only

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, customer

Magento allows to set minimum order amount. See system > configuration > sales > 
Minimum Order Amount

I want to set this option for Rs 200 for existing customers (with at least one completed order)  and skip it for new customers.

New customer is a customer with billing email is not associated to any completed order.

Comment: For first time customer your could either check by date register or check if they have any existing order

Comment: what is mean by first time customer

Comment: which magennto are you using?

Comment: Don't understand what is unclear in the question really.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible but you need some customization.

Magento check the min Order amount from `validateMinimumAmount` function of `Checkout address object`
means Sales quote address object (class `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address`)
.You need fetch quote `Customer email id from Quote and check is any order is exiting on this` email and put condition

```
 public function validateMinimumAmount()
    {
        $storeId = $this->getQuote()->getStoreId();
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('sales/minimum_order/active', $storeId)) {
            return true;
        }

        if ($this->getQuote()->getIsVirtual() && $this->getAddressType() == self::TYPE_SHIPPING) {
            return true;
        } elseif (!$this->getQuote()->getIsVirtual() && $this->getAddressType() != self::TYPE_SHIPPING) {
            return true;
        }

    $Ordercollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',  $this->getQuote()->getCustomerEmail());
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
    /* here condtion here */
    if(count($Ordercollection)>0){
        $amount = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/amount', $storeId);
        if ($this->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() < $amount) {
            return false;
        }
    }
        return true;
    }
```

**[NOte]** `For Complete Task Please rewrite model class  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address`

Comment: I have vote up for this one

Answer (score 1):

For the first time/new customers, this could be a solution for you:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId());
```

If the size of the collection is 0, the customer does not have an order so far.

You might also want to check for the order status to check if the customer has complete/processing/whatever orders:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId())
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can track customer by email id like Suppose customer is register first time at the time of checkout then when you check customer during checkout process **`sales_order_place_before Event`**.

using below code like customer is exsit or not.

```
protected function _customerExists($email, $websiteId = null)
{
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    if ($websiteId) {
       $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
    }
    $customer->loadByEmail($email);
    if ($customer->getId()) {
       return $customer;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In event Observer you can manage `sales Quote` object.